# NoMethodError in CommentsController#create and NoMethodError in LikesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, rubygems

I am having an undefined method error for likes and comments. Can you help? My repo branch is https://github.com/sja-thedude/Blog-App/tree/Add-Forms

[image]
[image]

likes_controller.rb

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    new_like = current_user.likes.new(
      user_id: current_user.id,
      post_id: @post.id
    )
    new_like.update_likes_counter
    if new_like.save
      redirect_to "/users/#{@post.user_id}/posts/#{@post.id}", notice: 'Success!'
    else
      render :new, alert: 'Error occured!'
    end
  end
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    new_comment = current_user.comments.new(
      text: comment_params,
      user_id: current_user.id,
      post_id: @post.id
    )
    new_comment.update_comments_counter
    if new_comment.save
      redirect_to "/users/#{@post.user_id}/posts/#{@post.id}", notice: 'Success!'
    else
      render :new, alert: 'Error occured!'
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:text)[:text]
  end
end
```

it says error in

app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:4:in `create' and app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:4:in` create'

Comment: What does your `current_user` method look like (probably to be found in your `application_controller`)?

Answer (score 2):

Your `current_user` method from `ApplicationController` is actually returning a list of users (although technically containing only 1 record).

Replace `User.limit(1)` to something like `User.take` or `User.first`.

Comment: I have got 2 new errors after changing that. 1. ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in Comments Controller#create 2.Template is missing

Comment: @SJA: well, these new problems are completely unrelated to this one.